# Database migration with different table structure

Tags: database, database-migration, rds

Legacy SQL Server database is on AWS RDS. Created another database with limited tables somewhat similar to the tables in the legacy database. What is a good tool that will help write migration scripts between different table structures that can be executed on AWS RDS. 
SSIS is not an option as RDS doesn't support that. 
Also would like to do this using some tool rather than EF or Dapper.

Comment: Check out Linked Servers and then use Insert statements from one db to the other using a View or Select.

Comment: Will this help in retaining the identity column values? I am thinking I will have to write additional queries when importing data based on the association of these primary keys.